# Add block after shipping methods on admin page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to add a `<select>` element after the shipping methods.

I've created a layout file in `Company\MyModule\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_create_load_block_shipping_method.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Company_MyModule::js/pickup_point_shipping.js"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block name="order.create.shipping.method.pickuppoint" class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template"
                       template="Company_MyModule::select_pickup_point.phtml"
                       after="order.create.shipping.method.form"  />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

But it does not appears on the page.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the reference, because it is a block instead of container:

```
<referenceBlock name="shipping_method">
        <block name="order.create.shipping.method.pickuppoint" class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template"
                   template="Company_MyModule::select_pickup_point.phtml"
                   after="order.create.shipping.method.form"  />
</referenceBlock>
```